# WAP in Python to generate the following series upto 500. #1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21,... 1+2=3,3+3=6,6+4=10,10+5=15

Tags: python

I want to increase i value by 1 every time I print A

```
n=1
m=3
A=m+3
i=4
for A in range(6,500,i):
  i+=1
  print (A,end=" ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation works using a `while` loop:

```
A = 1
i = 1
while A <= 500:
    print (A, end=" ")
    i += 1
    A += i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = 0 # The number to print

i = 1 # Number to increment by

# Loop while number less than or equal to 500
while num <= 500:
    num += i # Increment the number

    print(num) # Print the number
    i += 1 # Increment the increment
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loop implementation

```py
ans = 0
n=5 # number of terms you want in the series
for i in range(1,n+1) :
    ans = ans + i
    print(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=1
for i in range(2,500):
       if(a<=500):
          a=a+i
          print(a,end=" ")
```

> it prints the series u required